# Trying to install ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dvd

I downloaded a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 ISO file and wrote it to a DVD. I restarted the computer with BIOS set to boot from DVD drive as first boot device.

My computer now comes with Ubuntu 12.04 displayed at the screen where it asks for your user password. I am wondering why it does not say 13.04.

I am trying to get movie player to play DVDs but it will not load the addons. Does anyone know how to get 13.04 on my computer or how to make movie player work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/343223/edit) your question and add the link from which you downloaded your Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you preinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Take the official Ubuntu 13.04 iso [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent), and install VLC in the software center. It will work just fine...